# Angular2 populating Bootstrap 4 modal form inputs with previously clicked data

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular2-forms

Using Angular2, on my main page I have a table that sends the data of whichever row was clicked on to a Bootstrap 4 modal that pops up using a button on the main page. The modal contains form inputs that populate with the clicked row's data for editing. My problem is that if I edit one or both of the datefields and submit, those edited values populate the form inputs for the next row I click on to edit, but **ONLY** if I edited that first clicked row's dates.

For example, if row 1 has original dates `11/23/2016` and `11/26/2016` and row 2 has original dates `12/20/2016` and `12/22/2016` and I choose to edit row 1 first and change them to  `10/22/2016` and `10/31/2016`. Once I open the modal to edit row 2, it's dates will be `10/22/2016` and `10/31/2016`. But if I didn't edit row 1's dates, row 2's dates would show up properly as `12/20/2016` and `12/22/2016`. Additionally, the first two form inputs do not have this behavior.

I've tried using change detection in each method but none of that works for this issue. Also tried setting `receivedRow`'s dates to null, but that doesn't work either.

Main page (the button on the left in the row of 3 is what opens the modal):
[image]

Modal:
[image]

Typescript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'update-validation',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'update.component.html',
  providers: [DatePipe]
})

export class UpdateComponent {
  @Input() receivedRow:DataTable;
  public dt: NgbDateStruct;
  public dt2: NgbDateStruct;
  public startCheck: boolean = false;
  public endCheck: boolean = false;
  updateForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){
  this.updateForm = fb.group({
    'dataPoint' : [null, Validators.required],
    'ICCP' : [null, Validators.required],
    'startDate' : [null, Validators.required],
    'endDate' : [null, Validators.required]
    }, {validator: this.endDateAfterOrEqualValidator})
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    if(this.receivedRow){
      this.updateForm.controls['dataPoint'].setValue(this.receivedRow.tDataPoint);
      this.updateForm.controls['ICCP'].setValue(this.receivedRow.tICCP);
      this.updateForm.controls['startDate'].setValue(this.receivedRow.tStartDate);
      this.updateForm.controls['endDate'].setValue(this.receivedRow.tEndDate);
    }
   }

  resetForm(){
    location.reload();
    //this.updateForm.reset();
  }

  submitForm(value: any, originalRow: any){
    var dataPointID = originalRow.receivedRow.tDataPoint;
    for (let entry in DPS) {
      if (DPS[entry].tDataPoint === dataPointID) {
        DPS[entry].tDataPoint = String(this.updateForm.controls['dataPoint'].value);
        DPS[entry].tICCP = String(this.updateForm.controls['ICCP'].value);
        DPS[entry].tStartDate = String(this.updateForm.controls['startDate'].value);
        DPS[entry].tEndDate = String(this.updateForm.controls['endDate'].value);
      }
    }
  }

  getStartDate(){
    var month = this.receivedRow.tStartDate.substring(0,2);
    var day = this.receivedRow.tStartDate.substring(3,5);
    var year = this.receivedRow.tStartDate.substring(6,10);
    var dateToUse = new Date(Number(year),Number(month)-1,Number(day));
    let timestamp = this['startDate'] != null ? new Date(this['startDate'].year, this['startDate'].month-1, this['startDate'].day).getTime() : dateToUse.getTime();
    this.updateForm.controls['startDate'].setValue(this.datePipe.transform(timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
  }

  getEndDate(){
    var month = this.receivedRow.tEndDate.substring(0,2);
    var day = this.receivedRow.tEndDate.substring(3,5);
    var year = this.receivedRow.tEndDate.substring(6,10);
    var dateToUse = new Date(Number(year),Number(month)-1,Number(day));
    let timestamp = this['endDate'] != null ? new Date(this['endDate'].year, this['endDate'].month-1, this['endDate'].day).getTime() : dateToUse.getTime();
    this.updateForm.controls['endDate'].setValue(this.datePipe.transform(timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy'));
  }

  public showDatePick(selector):void {
    if(selector === 0) {
      this.startCheck = !this.startCheck
    } else {
      this.endCheck = !this.endCheck;
    }
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }

  endDateAfterOrEqualValidator(formGroup): any {
    var startDateTimestamp, endDateTimestamp;
    for(var controlName in formGroup.controls) {
      if (controlName.indexOf("startDate") !== -1) {
        tartDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls[controlName].value);
      }
      if (controlName.indexOf("endDate") !== -1) {
        endDateTimestamp = Date.parse(formGroup.controls[controlName].value);
      }
    }
    return (endDateTimestamp < startDateTimestamp) ? { endDateLessThanStartDate: true } : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified `submitForm` function to set `ngModel`'s `startDate` and `endDate` to `null` so that when `getStartDate` and `getEndDate` get called, `timestamp` in the `getStartDate` and `getEndDate` functions gets set to the date based on the row that is clicked and not the previously binded `startDate` and `endDate`.

```
submitForm(value: any, originalRow: any){
  var dataPointID = originalRow.receivedRow.tDataPoint;
  for (let entry in DPS) {
    if (DPS[entry].tDataPoint === dataPointID) {
      DPS[entry].tDataPoint = String(this.updateForm.controls['dataPoint'].value);
      DPS[entry].tICCP = String(this.updateForm.controls['ICCP'].value);
      DPS[entry].tStartDate = String(this.updateForm.controls['startDate'].value);
      DPS[entry].tEndDate = String(this.updateForm.controls['endDate'].value);
      this['startDate'] = null;
      this['endDate'] = null;
    }
  }
}
```